# cv::HoughLines on iOS fails with 'OpenCV Error: Assertion failed'

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv, edge-detection

I'm in the process of writing an app for iOS (using ARC) that does Canny edge detection and a Hough transform on an image and returns the y position of a horizontal line from a specific portion of it. To achieve this, I'm using the OpenCV library.

The Canny edge detection was easy enough to do, but the `cv::HoughLines` method fails every time, with a nasty 'Assertion failed' error. Here is a code snippet of what I'm attempting:

```
cv::cvtColor(myImage, inputImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

cv::Canny(inputImage, outputImage, 200, 600);

cv::Vec2f lines; // short for 'Vec<float, 2>'
cv::HoughLines(outputImage, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100);
```

At first, I wasn't sure whether Vec2f was correct, so I've tried also defining `lines` as `cv::Mat` instead... But then, `cv::HoughLines` doesn't return any data at all - at least not when checking with `cv::countNonZero(lines)`

Being fairly new to iOS and Objective-C (and coming from a less C-based coding background) any corrections and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Help yourself and paste the full error msg.

Comment: @karlphillip The full error that I get using Vec2f for 'lines' is `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (k == STD_VECTOR_MAT) in release, file /Users/robin/Projects/OpenCVForiPhone/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1369`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html#cv-houghlines) are pretty much clear about this:

```
void HoughLines(Mat& image, vector<Vec2f>& lines, double rho, double theta, int threshold, double srn=0, double stn=0)
```

That said, you need to change the parameter type to `std::vector<cv::Vec2f>`:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;
cv::HoughLines(outputImage, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100);
```

If you have any more problems try to look for examples that use this function, like the [FiducialDetector](http://low-cost-vision.googlecode.com/svn-history/r171/trunk/Vision/Fiducial/src/FiducialDetector.cpp).

Comment: Thanks very much @karlphillip, that's got rid of the error! It seems fairly obvious now, but I had no idea that I needed to use `std::`... I'm used to OOP, but not C++

Comment: Thanks! My problem was about using `cv::vector` instead of `cv::Vec2f`!